# Data flow task not getting completed and flat file generated is in locked state

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package deployed in 64-bit machine. The package is running fine if there are less number of records to be extracted and written to a file. We are using a data flow task for writing into file. However when we are runnning the package for large data extract, the data flow task is not getting completed and the file is getting locked. Please suggest a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you logging the progress of your package? Do you see anything in there? If not, can you log the progress?

If you are writing to a UNC, I would suggest writing locally and then moving the file where you want.

Comment: I am not logging the progress. However when I run the package directly, the status of the data flow task is in yellow and it is not getting completed. I have tried both writing to a UNC and locally. In both cases, the issue is occurring

Comment: I think you should add logging to the package.

Answer (score 0):

Some debugging directions: Check if you are getting same problem with a different type of target like excel or SQL table. Check which process is using the file currently (use tools like ProcessXP for this) and check if file is showing any contents at any intermediate stage. By the way are you using transactions?